# Javascript setFullYear() method changes the GMT time zone of the date. How to resolve this?

Tags: javascript

I have a date variable which is a clone of another date

```
let date = new Date(); //This date is in GMT+0100 Central European Standard Time

let cloneDate = new Date(date.getTime()); //This creates a prefect clone of the date
```

However, when I try to change the year of cloneDate using the setFullYear() method or the setMonth() or setDate(), etc., it changes the GMT timezone

```
  cloneDate.setFullYear(1883, 8, 11) //The result is a date in GMT+0009 Central European Summer Time instead of GMT+0100 Central European Standard Time
```

This creates erros in my function.

Does anyone know how to solve this in order to get a cloneDate with the new year, month, day, but also in the same GMT timezone?

Thanks

Comment: many countries currently in CET timezone did not adopt that as a standard until after 1883 - in fact late 19th century is when standardised timezones were slowly being adopted around the world, so you'll get a lot of anomalies - oh, and by the way, you can just do `let cloneDate = new Date(date)` to get what you call a "perfect clone" - it doesn't matter which date you set to 1883, there's going to be issues because back then timezones were not standardised

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "*GMT timezone*", neither of your dates is printed using GMT?

Comment: If you want to ignore timezones, especially your system timezone, always use UTC. `new Date(Date.UTC(1883, 8, 11)).toUTCString()`